# unable to cast object of type 'system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction' to type 'system.transactions.safeIknown'

Tags: c#, asp.net

i use entity framwork.
in my query
Sometimes this error occurs.
What is the solution?
Is it related to the entity version of the framework? I brought it from 6 to 5, but again, this error sometimes happens.
my code:

```
var PersonDetail = (from p in DBContext.People
                        where p.PersonID==1

                        select new
                        {
                            p.PersonID,

                            roles = p.RolePersons.Select(r => new
                            {
                                r.Role.RoleID,
                                r.Role.Title        
            }),
                        }).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: Can you post the line(s) of code that produces this exception?

Comment: edited question and add code.

Comment: There appears to be nothing wrong with this code.   Do you use any manual transactions ?  I guess it could be something in OnModelCreating or some other configuration that EF doesn't like.